# Использование if и elseif в конструкции match

Tags: php, if, switch, match

Хотел заменить `switch` на `match`, но не пойму, как организовать конструкцию `if` ... `elseif` внутри блока `match`.

В конструкции `switch` всё просто:

```
switch ($lesson) {
case 'Русский':
    if ($a=='3') {
        echo 'Удовлетворительно!';
    }
    elseif($a=='4'){
        echo 'Хорошо';
    }
    elseif($a=='5'){
        echo 'Отлично';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Плохо';
    }
    break;        
}
```

С конструкцией `match` такое не прокатывает:

```
match ($lesson){
'Русский' =>[
    if ($a=='3') {
        echo 'Удовлетворительно!';
    }
    elseif($a=='4'){
        echo 'Хорошо';
    }
    elseif($a=='5'){
        echo 'Отлично';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Плохо';
    }
      
  ]
};
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "if", expecting "]"

Как в `match` использовать конструкцию `if` ... `elseif`?

Comment: никак, можно использовать функции

Comment: Это косяк. Для каждого блока создавать функцию? Хотел использовать его чтоб укоротить запись, так как match позволяет для нескольких элементов прописать одно действие "'Русский','Алгебра'=>..."

Comment: Можно конечно не создавать функции, использовать тернарный оператор, и т.д. но не надо это делать лишь в погоне за коротким кодом. Важна читабельность.

Answer (score 1):

```php
echo match ($lesson) {
    'Русский' => match ($a) {
        '3' => 'Удовлетворительно!',
        '4' => 'Хорошо',
        '5' => 'Отлично',
        default => 'Плохо',
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте несколько аргументов в одном match

```
echo match ([$lesson,$a]) {
    ['Русский','3'] => 'Удовлетворительно!',
    ['Русский','4'] => 'Хорошо',
    ['Русский','5'] => 'Отлично',
    default => 'Плохо',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не косяк, это так и задумано. Вы пытаетесь использовать конструкцию не по назначению (`match` выдает соответствия только по выражениям, когда как вы хотите использовать конструкции).

Потом, когда стало можно в массивах писать конструкции?
`'value' => [ if() { ... } ]` вызовет синтаксическую ошибку. Что, собственно, Вы и видите.

На самом деле Вам тут `match` не нужен. Конструкция ради конструкции, не иначе. Продолжайте использовать `switch` - это правильная конструкция для Вашей ситуации.

Если прям очень хочется, то можно использовать замыкание и сразу же его вызвать, это будет работать:

```
<?php

$lesson = 'Русский';
$a = '3';

echo match ($lesson) {
    'Русский' => call_user_func(function () use ($a) {
            if ($a == 3) {
                return 'Удовлетворительно!';
            } else if ($a == 4){
                return 'Хорошо';
            } else if ($a == 5){
                return 'Отлично';
            } else {
                return 'Плохо';
            }
        })
};
```

Comment: Но вообще тут ни `match`, ни `switch` не нужны. Логику можно написать куда короче без повторов.

Answer (score 0):

```
match ($lesson){
'Русский' => function {
    if ($a == '3') {
        echo 'Удовлетворительно!';
    } elseif ($a == '4'){
        echo 'Хорошо';
    } elseif ($a == '5'){
        echo 'Отлично';
    } else {
        echo 'Плохо';
    }  
  }
};
```